# Rewrite JSON data within a .js file when submitting HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, json, database, forms

Forgive me if I dont describe my problem very well. I am a beginner with this.

Basically, I have a webpage which displays nine numerical values and beside these values is a form. The numerical values are stored as JSON data inside a .js file.

What I want is for when I type in a new numerical value into the form and click on submit, I want all the current values to move down one place (the last one getting deleted) and the new value I have entered to replace the first data entry.

I need this to work offline, so I cant use a regular database like MySql, and there will never be more than 9 items of data stored. Thats why I thought saving the data in the .js file would be best.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically, you do not have write permission on any modern browsers.

Comment: Since you said you going to make the page offline, I would recommend using `localStorage` to store the data.